# I have a long history of suffering from power abuse, currently getting rejected research/grad applications

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, supervision, abuse

I am from India. I have done B.Sc and M.Sc in Physics so far.
My BSc is from one of the top colleges in India (top 10). However, the professors were very narrow-minded when it came to academia. I got intentionally screwed over and given low marks on exams as I gave answers from established books, rather than their notes. I got the evaluated papers through the Right to Information Act after a long fight and found out that I was right. Most of my answers were correct as per books and outside professors. My college professors either undermarked them or gave no marks for the right answers. I passed with a second-class B.Sc degree in Physics (48%). The college didn't cooperate and was hostile, and there was no way for improvement without a court battle.

In India for M.Sc, universities arrange nationwide entrance exams. I ranked top in many entrance exams for M.Sc in top universities but didn't get into solely because of my UG marks. I lost a year and the next year got into a relatively lower-grade university for an M.Sc.

This M.Sc was entirely coursework based. I got a 7/10 CGPA, which is considered a distinction, where the top scorer got 8. Final exams were delayed by several months due to Covid. Even during my M.Sc, I had bad experiences. Got marked lowest in some courses even after writing everything right. I know it was intentional as the professor was racist towards me due to my ethnic background in India. Even after I showed and proved that my answers were current they still gave me the lowest in class.

During my M.Sc, I took part in a scientific poster presentation at a research institution and many of the visiting foreign professors liked it. They were so interested that they even took my email ID and were in touch with me for a long time. Unfortunately during the second the organisers in the institute kicked me away. They took me to a corner and were saying filth about my background and I was taking the attention from them.

Even during M.Sc, I visited another research institute for a conference and there I helped them realize a problem and its solution for their upcoming big research lab. It was a multinational collaborative experimental project and the professors were so impressed that they offered me positions but my primary interest is in theory, so I chose not to go.

After my M.Sc, I had a hard time getting into research internships in India but got one with a professor eventually to work in theory. He gave a a lot to read: books, papers, and such. For starting work a lot of coursework is needed for this research sector. I was hopeful and worked day and night to grasp all the materials, read papers, learn coding, do calculations for the professors' papers. But as time progressed he started to defer his part of the research, not replying to emails or calls properly, delaying meetings but still insisting I to stay and that he would make some time next month, and so on. But he never did and after a few more months I realized that he's not going to ever. He even gave out no recommendations for PhD applications and when I asked, he told me that, I shouldn't have put all of my eggs in one basket.

I got depressed and even started to apply to the UK for some research masters for research experiences, as officially I don't have any, and PhD applications are complicated but not getting any luck with any university. It's been one year of searching. Most professors either do not reply to emails, universities reject citing not good academics, or professors already have students.

I have a long history of getting abused in India and am tired of fighting. I have lost five academic years so far and still staying in for a quality research position but not getting any. If anyone can give me any advice, I will highly appreciate it.

Comment: You have been accepted for experimental physics, but not for theoretical physics. Why don't you accept it? It would be an opportunity to improve your CV (after you have a couple papers published nobody cares about your grades). Besides, isn't it the case that many theoretical physicists started in some applied field? (Einstein worked in a patents office for goodness sake!)

Comment: Although it was an experimental conference, they had the calculations wrong theoretically which I pointed out. My strong suit lies in theory, I am not particularly good in forging experimental setups. Then again, that offer was during my M.Sc, years have passed after that.

Answer (score 9):

First, I would recommend getting assistance with your mental health from a trusted professional. It sounds like you've been through a lot.

Second, I do not think that people will find the story of abuse at multiple levels particularly credible in a highly competitive context. Even if your story is accurate on all fronts, the problem is that you will be competing with people who received good grades at all stages and praise from their advisors. There will be applicants who have struggled at some stage but subsequently demonstrated growth and success. The job of an admissions committee is to accept the applicants that they think have the best chances to succeed, not to make the world right for someone who has suffered, so those stories will be better received than yours.

If all of your applications for further graduate study are denied and you have applied to a range of institutions with a range of selectivity, it may be time to look for employment in your field without further academic study. Most people do not obtain a PhD, and most people who obtain a PhD eventually take a job that does not require a PhD; there are too few PhD-requiring jobs out there, especially in areas like theory that either do not have or are far from having immediate financial impact for someone that has the money to pay for it.

Comment: I can't afford therapy, I have been giving tuitions to make ends meet. I don't wanna do PhD just for jobs but for research. I am still looking for some positions that may take me.I am concerned about whether should I write the reasons for my gap years. I haven't done that so far in applications.

Comment: @JAMES213 That sounds like a good reason to find a non-PhD job. I understand that you'd like to do PhD research but it sounds like you haven't been accepted anywhere. Rather than thinking about your past struggles you need to look to your future. You can apply again but I do not see anything in your descriptions here that would improve an application. If there are any academics you know personally that you trust you could ask them to help review your applications and look for areas to improve.

Comment: There are still some universities to apply, that's why I am asking for any suggestions. Unfortunately, I don't know any foreign professors to review my application. I am hoping to get some feedback here. Are you a professor?